# 13.10 won't load any web pages

Tags: 13.10

After my upgrade to 13.10 (saucy salamander) fire fox won't load any pages, not even the startup page I continuously get a "server not found" error. What could it be? I've looked and no one else has asked about this problem

Answer (score 2):

Generally a "server not found" message means that there is no active internet connection. Check to see if this is the issue first.

You may have to unplug both your Modem and router (if applicable) for at least 30 seconds, then plug them back in.